# Shift left by custom number

Tags: fpga, verilog, led-matrix

I have a 5*7 dot matrix in my FPGA, and I need to "walk" a dot. The `data` is 35 bits long, and only one bit should be 1 (visible). The upper-right dot is (0;0), the lower-left is `data[34]`. The problem is that I can't figure out how I should shift a '1' to the specified position.

```
reg [34:0] data;
reg [ 2:0] x, y;

always @ (posedge clk16M) begin
    if (rst) begin
        x    <= 3'b0;
        y    <= 3'b0;
        data <= 35'b1;
    end

    .. calculate x and y ..  

end

always @ (*) begin
    data <= 35'b1 << (x * 3'd7 + y);
end
```

It doesn't move the dot, however, `x` and `y`'s value are fine. They change when they should.

Comment: You realise that you are assigning a value to ```data``` in two different always blocks right? This isn't allowed, so I'm amazed your code compiles.

Comment: @TomCarpenter All the simulators I know allow assigning in multiple blocks, it is just not synthesisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
always @ (*) begin
    data <= 35'b1 << (x * 3'd7 + y);
end
```

I think you may have an integer overflow issue. I would try changing 3'd7 to 6'd7 to make sure the calculations happen with wide enough values. (i'm not positive what the verilog rules are with regards operation sizes in complex expressions like this)

I would also get rid of the "data <= 35'b1;" in the first always block. You should only set each signal in one always block.

Comment: When I removed `data <= 35'b1;` it worked fine. First I used only one `always` block, and forgot to remove it later.

Answer (score 0):

Using a two dimensional array would be easier and better choice.
for example
something like 
reg [6:0]data[0:4];

and use variables x and y directly to position the bit data[x][y] with x=0 and y=0 would be the (0,0) data point.

Comment: In an other project I used arrays like that, but I couldn't get the values by `data[x][y]`, only `reg d1 = data[x]; d1[y];`. I need to learn how it works later.

Comment: Using it should be fairly easy i have used it in few of my projects.